# C# use reflection to capture exception throw

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

Is there a way using reflection or another methodology inside a catch block to get the exception type that has been thrown, along with the stack trace without appending the catch(Exception ex) parameter?

I want a way catch all exceptions and mitigate the code analysis finding for overly broad catch.

```
catch
{
     //Include Reflection here to get error thrown information

     divRecordNotFound.Visible = true;
     labelRecordNotFound.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}", ValidNS.Properties.Resoures.ErrorValue); 
     divRecordFound.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: `I want a way catch all exceptions and mitigate the code analysis finding for overly broad catch` - So you want a broad catch without the code analysis tool telling you it's bad? Even *if* this were possible, you don't gain anything from it. Just put in the `catch (Exception ex)` and add a rule to your code analysis tool to ignore this particular broad catch. You shouldn't mutilate your code to make an analysis tool happy.

Comment: I can't imagine a usefull link between catching exceptions and reflection. You should not detour warnings from code analysis with cumbersome solutions.

Comment: This should still be reported as overly broad catch unless the code assesment tool is buggy.

Comment: Rob - your comment is the answer. "You shouldn't mutilate your code to make an analysis tool happy." Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By doing a `catch (Exception ex)` you also catch all exceptions which derive from `Exception`.
If you then want the type of it, you can just call `ex.GetType()`.
Hope it helped ;)